# Cannot progammatically change IIS website's physical path

Tags: c#, iis

I'm trying to change the path to some of my IIS sites programmatically. The change only takes
effect only for one of the sites (the same one) and not all of them. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
using WebAdministration = Microsoft.Web.Administration;

using (WebAdministration.ServerManager serverManager = new WebAdministration.ServerManager())
{
    serverManager.Sites.ToList().ForEach(site =>
    {
        site.Stop();
        serverManager.CommitChanges();
        //ChangeDirectoryOfSite(site
        site.Applications.ToList().ForEach(app =>
        {
            //ChangeDirectoryOfApplication
            //if (app.VirtualDirectories?.Attributes["path"]?.Value...
            app.VirtualDirectories.Attributes["path"].Value = ...
            //if (app.VirtualDirectories?.Attributes["physicalPath"]?.Value?
            app.VirtualDirectories.Attributes["physicalPath"].Value = ...
            app.VirtualDirectories.ToList().ForEach(virtualDir =>
            {
                //ChangeDirectoryOfVirtualDirectoy
                //if (virtualDir.Attributes["path"].Value...
                virtualDir.Attributes["path"].Value = ...
                //if (virtualDir.Attributes["physicalPath"].Value...
                virtualDir.Attributes["physicalPath"].Value = ...
            }
            site.Start()
        }
        serverManager.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: It makes no sense to iterate with `ForEach` if your goal is just to change the site physical path, as that only requires modification to root virtual directory of the root application under that site.

Comment: Foreach just a method to let you list all sites and path information. You need to get target site and change it like this: `site.Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath = physicalPath;`

Comment: The purpose of the iterations is unrelated to the question, so I excluded it as much as possible  from the actual question. Giving a clear question to the actual the problem. If you're interested: the purpose of the loop is that the nature of the website is quite complex different parts can be updated and tested separately, none of this business logic is included in the question. My goal is to automate this existing process a little more that what I can currently already do with just the command line. Using the command line you can specify a particular site to change to a give value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was to `.CommitChanges()` after each value change:

I marked the code changes with `// <-- Add this` below

```
using WebAdministration = Microsoft.Web.Administration;

using (WebAdministration.ServerManager serverManager = new WebAdministration.ServerManager())
{
    serverManager.Sites.ToList().ForEach(site =>
    {
        site.Stop();
        serverManager.CommitChanges();
        //ChangeDirectoryOfSite(site
        site.Applications.ToList().ForEach(app =>
        {
            //ChangeDirectoryOfApplication
            //if (app.VirtualDirectories?.Attributes["path"]?.Value...
            app.VirtualDirectories.Attributes["path"].Value = ...
            serverManager.CommitChanges(); // <--- Add this
            //if (app.VirtualDirectories?.Attributes["physicalPath"]?.Value?
            app.VirtualDirectories.Attributes["physicalPath"].Value = ...
            serverManager.CommitChanges(); // <--- Add this
            app.VirtualDirectories.ToList().ForEach(virtualDir =>
            {
                //ChangeDirectoryOfVirtualDirectoy
                //if (virtualDir.Attributes["path"].Value...
                virtualDir.Attributes["path"].Value = ...
                serverManager.CommitChanges(); // <--- Add this
                //if (virtualDir.Attributes["physicalPath"].Value...
                virtualDir.Attributes["physicalPath"].Value = ...
                serverManager.CommitChanges(); // <--- Add this                
            });
            site.Start()
        });
        serverManager.CommitChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: the code is not valid and does not work  (even after filling the variables and adding the missing parentheses)

Comment: The code does work for me, I added the missing parenthesis. Maybe you can expand on what the problem is your facing/trying to solve rather than down vote something unrelated to your problrm.

Answer (score 0):

To change the physicalpath, you need to change the **property** of one specific site, not those attributes.

```
 using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
   {
       serverManager.Sites["{site-name}"].Stop();
       serverManager.Sites["{site-name}"].Applications["/"].VirtualDirectories["/"].PhysicalPath = "{your-path-here}";
       serverManager.CommitChanges();
       serverManager.Sites["{site-name}"].Start();
   }
```